# How To Split Header text in more than two lines in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in learning wordpress website development.
i have written title and its being shown on a single line i want same text to be displayed on more than one line,

site url is : http://cics1.mitpune.edu.in/

my title is : MAEER'S MIT (Corporate Information & Computing Services)

i want this title to be displayed in following manner

```
MAEER'S MIT(First Line)
Corporate Information & Computing Services(second Line)
(CICS)(last line))
```

how should i do this .
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Use <br /> tag in between words.

    MAEER'S MIT <br />
    Corporate Information & Computing Services <br />
    (CICS) <br />

Add title like this
```

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit you header.php file in the following way code:
Look for the Div class="supportive-text"

and add the following

```
<div class="support-text">
  MAEER'S MIT <br>(Corporate Information &amp; Computing Services)<br>CICS          
</div>
```

Note that is in the best practice to use a wordpress child theme to make changes to the core theme files as with using the child theme you will not lose the custmisation changes you have made when parent theme is updated.